# How to convert date to the first day of month in a PySpark Dataframe column?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame:

```
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2017-01-25|
|2017-01-21|
|2017-01-12|
+----------+
```

Here is the code the create above DataFrame:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
rdd = sc.parallelize([("2017/11/25",), ("2017/12/21",), ("2017/09/12",)])
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, ["date"]).withColumn("date", f.to_date(f.col("date"), "yyyy/MM/dd"))
df.show()
```

I want a new column with the first date of month for each row, just replace the day to "01" in all the dates

```
+----------++----------+
|      date| first_date|
+----------++----------+
|2017-11-25| 2017-11-01|
|2017-12-21| 2017-12-01|
|2017-09-12| 2017-09-01|
+----------+-----------+
```

There is a last_day function in PySpark.sql.function, however, there is no first_day function.

I tried using date_sub to do this but did not work: I get a column not Iterable error because the second argument to date_sub cannot be a column and has to be an integer.

```
f.date_sub(f.col('date'), f.dayofmonth(f.col('date')) - 1 )
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `trunc`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.withColumn("first_date", f.trunc("date", "month")).show()

+----------+----------+
|      date|first_date|
+----------+----------+
|2017-11-25|2017-11-01|
|2017-12-21|2017-12-01|
|2017-09-12|2017-09-01|
+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the beginning of the month with the `trunc` function (as Alper) mentioned or with the `date_trunc` method.  The `trunc` function returns a date column and the `date_trunc` function returns a time column.  Suppose you have the following DataFrame:

```
+----------+
| some_date|
+----------+
|2017-11-25|
|2017-12-21|
|2017-09-12|
|      null|
+----------+
```

Run the `trunc` and `date_trunc` functions:

```py
datesDF\
  .withColumn("beginning_of_month_date", trunc(col("some_date"), "month"))\
  .withColumn("beginning_of_month_time", date_trunc("month" ,col("some_date")))\
  .show()
```

Observe the result:

```
+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
| some_date|beginning_of_month_date|beginning_of_month_time|
+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|2017-11-25|             2017-11-01|    2017-11-01 00:00:00|
|2017-12-21|             2017-12-01|    2017-12-01 00:00:00|
|2017-09-12|             2017-09-01|    2017-09-01 00:00:00|
|      null|                   null|                   null|
+----------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
```

Print the schema to confirm the column types:

```
root
 |-- some_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- beginning_of_month_date: date (nullable = true)
 |-- beginning_of_month_time: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Scala users should use the `beginningOfMonthDate` and `beginningOfMonthTime` functions defined in [spark-daria](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria).

PySpark users should use the `beginning_of_month_date` and `beginning_of_month_time` functions defined in [quinn](https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn).

Notice how the `trunc` function takes the column argument first and the `date_trunc` takes the column argument second.  The `trunc` method is poorly named - it's part of the functions package, so it's easy to mistakenly think this function is for string truncation.  It's surprising that `date_trunc` is returning a timestamp result... sounds like it should return a date result.

Just make sure to wrap these functions with descriptive function / UDF names so your code is readable.  See [here](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/start-end-month-last-day-date-trunc/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is syntactical error, Can you please change f.dayofmonth -> dayofmonth and try. Expression looks fine.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

f.date_sub(f.col('Match_date'),dayofmonth(f.col('Match_date')) - 1 )
```