# Add a new Date column based on the year and month of another date column pyspark

Tags: dataframe, date, pyspark

I have the following dataframe

```
id | name  | created_date |
---|-------|--------------|
1  | abs   | 2020-03-14   |
2  | csn   | 2019-05-20   |
```

I want to add another date column based on created_date column. I want to take year and month from created_date and days should be always 1. So that output dataframe should be as follows.

```
id | name  | created_date |new_date  |
---|-------|--------------|----------|
1  | abs   | 2020-03-14   |2020-03-01|
2  | csn   | 2019-05-20   |2019-05-01|
```

I am not sure how to implement this using pyspark.

Comment: Use `trunc`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349048/how-to-convert-date-to-the-first-day-of-month-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert date to the first day of month in a PySpark Dataframe column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48349048/how-to-convert-date-to-the-first-day-of-month-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-column)